# SharePoint 2010 permissions issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've created a site recently using team sites and some sub sites that inherit from this site.

the structure is

top level - site x

sub sites site w & site e(these inherit)

sub sub sites(under site w) site d and site r (broken inheritance)

With a standard user i cannot access site w even though NT authenticated user is in the visitors group of site x

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Cheers
         Truez

Comment: Can you confirm that site W is secured with the same groups as site X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie error!

I removed all of the custom web parts and the permissions worked perfectly.

One of the web parts was trying to recurse through a sub web which the test user didn't have access to.

I thought i had covered this by running with elevated permissions but upon further investigation i was passing an SPWeb object in which still had the old unelevated context.

Instead of passing the web object in i passed in the site ID and created the Web within the run with elevated privlages.

If anyone doesn't understand then comment and i will write an example code sample to explain further.

Cheers
Truez